# Example with SubscribeOn / ObserveOn in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm trying to use RX in Andorid Xamarin.
Do you know how to use:
`Observable.SubscribeOn(..)` to declare using thread from default pool to do background tasks
`Observable.ObserveOn(..)` to redirect events from Observable to UI thread

According to `SubscribeOn` I tried all ISchedulers
from
`System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll / System.Reactive.Concurrency`
that is:

```
NewThreadScheduler.Default
TaskPoolScheduler.Default
ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance
```

and nothing works.

On the ohter hand [if possible] I don't want to manually:
- create my thread inside Observable
 - use RunOnUiThread in Observer

**= = = update = = =**

Test results for `NewThreadScheduler.Default`
Code:

```
Console.WriteLine("creating ole");
var ole = Observable.Create<string>(suber =>
{
   Console.WriteLine("inside ole");
   Thread.Sleep(5000);
   suber.OnNext("point1");
   suber.OnCompleted();
   Console.WriteLine("ole completed");
   return Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("observer unsubscribed"));
});
ole.SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default);
Console.WriteLine("subscribing");
oleSub = ole.Subscribe(s => Console.WriteLine("result: " + s));
Console.WriteLine("subscribed");
```

Output:

```
creating ole
subscribing
inside ole
result: point1
ole completed
observer unsubscribed
subscribed
```

Conclusion:
Observable content is executed in main thread, although is expected to run its own thread: `ole.SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default);`

Comment: "and nothing works" but what do you actually see? I use these methods often in Xamarin without issue. `myObservable.SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rx is based on Functional programming, of which a key tenant is side-effect free programming.

when you create `var ole = Observable.Create...` you are creating an observable sequence. This sequence will have behavior when something subscribes to it.

When you then try to set up the Subscribe on `ole.SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default);` you are decorating the `ole` observable sequence with *SubscribeOn* behavior, however as this is a side-effect free operation, it returns a new observable sequence. You don't assign the returned instance to anything. i.e. the `ole.SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default);` line of code does nothing.

You then go back to the original unmodified `ole` observable sequence and subscribe to that.

I have two suggestions

1. Create a Logging helper operator to remove all the `Console.Write` noise in your code. This will both be a useful thing for you to use when debugging your Rx code and will also allow you to learn how to create an Rx operator (that will be side effect free). https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/34ac4f3536b00bbe259384d3bf0e8746da3311cc/Instrumentation/Logging.md
2. Chain your methods so that you actually get the behavior you want.

Here we use the `SubscribeOn` method properly. We also use the `Log` extension method you can write yourself from the link above.

```
var ole = Observable.Create<string>(obs=>
{       
    Thread.Sleep(5000); //Dont use Thread.Sleep and Rx :-)
    obs.OnNext("point1");
    obs.OnCompleted();
    return Disposable.Empty;
});
var oleSubscription = ole
    .Log("ole")
    .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
    .ObserveOn(/*What ever Android's UI Thread Scheduler is*/)
    .Subscribe(s => Console.WriteLine("result: " + s));
```

Also note that I have added the `ObserveOn` operator too. I strongly urge users of these two methods to only use them on the final subscriber (probably your ViewModel?) and only use them as the last operators before the `Subscribe` method as above.

More help :

- http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html
- http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/18_UsageGuidelines.html#UsageGuidelines

Comment: In short: I subscribed to wrong Observable. After @Lee fix code works. Tnx!